# How to add an HTML block to MailChimp template

Tags: javascript, php, html, mailchimp, newsletter

I'm trying to add HTML code to my custom template on MailChimp.  For each newsletter I am using a widget code from my affiliate network.  I think the best way to add in the HTML code into each MailChimp newsletter is to add an HTML block to my template.  However, I can't figure out how to do this. Does anyone know how I could do this, or what the best solution would be?

Here is some of the code I've tried, and it does not work to make an HTML element.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCodeBlock" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;" mc:repeatable mc:variant="HTML">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;">
            <div class="mcnTextContent" style="color:#656565;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12px;line-height:150%;text-align:center;" mc:edit="html">
                Use your own custom HTML
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is an example of the type of code I would like to add in to each newsletter. (The code creates a product widget.)

```html
<!-- COLLECTIVE WIDGET CODE START -->
<div class="shopsense-widget" style="text-align:center" data-options="%7B%22widgetId%22%3A%22599ae0a3dd4edb8d76b68fef%22%2C%22version%22%3A1%2C%22pid%22%3A%22uid8481-39636191-81%22%2C%22size%22%3A150%2C%22columns%22%3A3%2C%22rows%22%3A2%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopstyle.com%2Fapi%2Fv2%22%2C%22iframeHeight%22%3A390%2C%22iframeWidth%22%3A555%7D">
    <script>
        !function(doc,s,id){ var e, p, cb; if(!doc.getElementById(id)) { e = doc.createElement(s); e.id = id; cb = new Date().getTime().toString(); p = '//shopsensewidget.shopstyle.com/widget-script.js?cb=1503338936395?cb=' + cb; e.src = p; doc.body.appendChild(e); } if(typeof window.ss_shopsense === 'object'){ if(doc.readyState === 'complete'){ window.ss_shopsense.init(); } } }(document, 'script', 'shopsensewidget-script');
    </script>
    <iframe src="//shopsensewidget.shopstyle.com/#/?options=%7B%22widgetId%22%3A%22599ae0a3dd4edb8d76b68fef%22%2C%22version%22%3A1%2C%22pid%22%3A%22uid8481-39636191-81%22%2C%22size%22%3A150%2C%22columns%22%3A3%2C%22rows%22%3A2%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopstyle.com%2Fapi%2Fv2%22%2C%22iframeHeight%22%3A390%2C%22iframeWidth%22%3A555%7D"
         height="390px"
         width="555px"
         seamless style="border: 0;">
    </iframe>
</div>
<!-- COLLECTIVE WIDGET CODE END -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are trying to add script to an HTML email, which just isn't possible nor recommended. You CAN fake a server side solution, but direct injection of a script is a no-go.

Read [this article](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email) for some clarity on the subject :)